# reactjs server doesnt auto refresh if i make changes in index.js

Tags: reactjs

**I am facing issue that if I makes changes in index.js or app.js it and the browser doesn't auto refresh the page .If I make changes in index.html the auto refresh works .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **.env** file then write in file

```
 FAST_REFRESH=false
```